# How can I play audio file was downloaded in app?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I want to know how I can play file was downloaded in app , I download a music file then I want to play it in the app , I found this func and use it to download .
Thanks at all.

```
func downloadSong (_ sender:UIButton) {
    if let url = URL(string: startURL) {
        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {
            print("Downloading started")

            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                print("Downloading finished")

                do {
                    // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                    print("File moved to documents folder")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AVAudioPlayer with your destinationUrl

```
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:destinationUrl error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; 
[player play];
```

Swift ver:

```
let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl)
player?.numberOfLoops = -1;
player?.play()
```